Coxeter polynomial of bouncing Dyck paths
I am trying to understand Gjergji Zaimi's answer in the post What are the periodic Dyck paths?. I am currently asking myself (in the proof of the theorem) why is $$det(xI_n−ϕ_D)=1+xdet(xI_n−1−ϕ_{D′})$$ where D is a bouncing Dyck path with series [c_1,...,c_n] and D' has series [c_2,...,c_n]. So far I have that $$det(xI_n-\phi_D)=xdet(xI_n-\phi_{D'})+(-1)^{j+1}det((xI_n-\phi_D)_{j\,1})$$ So I need to prove that $1=(-1)^{j+1}det((xI_n-\phi_D)_{j\,1})$. Using Gjergji Zaimis idea: "One needs to show that there is a unique permutation not fixing 1, that has nonzero contribution in the determinant expansion", we get that $$det((xI_n-\phi_D)_{j\,1})=\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n-1}} sgn(\sigma ) \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}a_{i\, \sigma(i)}.$$ At this point, I can't really figure out how to proceed. I was thinking that I could use $ϕ_D=A_n+Y_D−X^T_D$ but this is not true for all Dyck paths (or even bouncing ones).

Why did you delete your previous similar question?: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484009

Unfortunately I found a counterexample. Thats why I explicitly mentioned here that $\phi_D$ does not always look the way as stated in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303487/what-are-the-periodic-dyck-paths. You can also see in the comments of Gjergji Zaimi's answer that part of his answer needs some more work. I am trying to solve it but for now, I haven't fully understood the counterdirection.
